# Subsetting and replacing in a list variable nested in a dataframe

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements, subset

Here is my dataframe example. It includes a column variable, named "dta" which is a single list of n values I want to keep for each of my scenario:

```
set.seed(777)
df <- data.frame(theo = numeric(),
                 size = numeric(),
                 dta  = I(list()))
df[ 1: 5,"theo"]  <- qlnorm(0.1, meanlog=0, sdlog=1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
df[ 6:10,"theo"]  <- qlnorm(0.2, meanlog=0, sdlog=1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
df[ 1: 5,"size"]  <- 10
df[ 6:10,"size"]  <- 20
for(i in 1:10){
     df$dta[i] <- list(rlnorm(df$size[i], meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1))
     }
df
str(df)
```

This should give a df like:

```
        theo size          dta
1  0.2776062   10 1.631967....
2  0.2776062   10 0.737667....
3  0.2776062   10 0.131252....
4  0.2776062   10 1.937334....
5  0.2776062   10 0.739868....
6  0.4310112   20 4.631176....
7  0.4310112   20 2.610180....
8  0.4310112   20 0.175918....
9  0.4310112   20 3.501670....
10 0.4310112   20 0.588178....
```

or:

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ theo: num  0.278 0.278 0.278 0.278 0.278 ...
 $ size: num  10 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20
 $ dta :List of 10
  ..$ : num  1.632 0.671 1.667 0.671 5.148 ...
  ..$ : num  0.738 1.056 0.152 0.967 10.089 ...
  ..$ : num  0.131 1.256 0.457 3.574 4.211 ...
  ..$ : num  1.937 2.359 3.496 0.297 4.587 ...
  ..$ : num  0.74 0.66 0.481 0.434 1.874 ...
  ..$ : num  4.631 0.298 10.28 0.933 1.286 ...
  ..$ : num  2.61 0.472 0.251 1.61 0.303 ...
  ..$ : num  0.176 0.566 2.156 0.407 3.52 ...
  ..$ : num  3.502 1.748 1.283 0.648 1.359 ...
  ..$ : num  0.588 0.392 2.447 1.926 0.86 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

Now, I want to subset that list in such a way that:

1. for each list, each value is compared with the fixed value "theo" stored in the dataframe
2. when that value is below or equal to "theo", then recode that value NA

Here is a working code and gives me exactly what I want:

```
df$dta2 <- df$dta
for(i in 1:10){
     df$dta2[[i]] [ df$dta2[[i]] <= df$theo[i] ] <- NA
     }
```

However I was wondering is there is a way to get the same result with a single line of code and no "for loop" to proceed with a conditional replacement of values contained in a list which is nested in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
df$dta3 <- Map(function(x,y) replace(x, x<=y, NA), df$dta, df$theo)
all.equal(df$dta2, df$dta3, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much akrun. What a nice way to do this :)

Comment: akrun, I don't get "TRUE" for the all.equal testing. I get the following error message: [1] "la cible est NULL, l'actuel est list" or "target is NULL, actual is list". Any idea to make all.equal run?

Comment: @Zef My code was based on the example you showed.  Looks like there are some NULL elements in the original data

Comment: My mistake, sorry.